# Confused about bits and bytes: How can 10 bits represent 1024 bytes?

Tags: binary

If we have 10 bits, then we can access 2^10 = 1024 different addresses with it, but we say that with 10 bits, we can show 1 kilobytes which is 1024 bytes. I can't understand this. Isn't 1 byte equal to 8 bits? That doesn't make any sense to me cause this basically means 1024 addresses which are made of 8 bits which is impossible. 8 bits can show up to 256 different addresses, right?

Comment: It appears like you are using "addresses" as synonymous with "values".  An address merely indicates a storage location; it doesn't tell how many bits of content that location may contain or what content might be stored there.

Comment: With 10 bits, you can address 1024 of anything, be it bits, bytes, apples, oranges, people, or hard drives containing multiple terabytes of data per each.

Comment: @Antonio51 I think that is a bit ambiguous what you mean.

Comment: How is this related to EE?

Comment: @Antonio51 That was not what I meant. 10 bits still is not 1024 bytes, but it is not clear if you mean that or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at a byte as a box that holds eight bits.

Each box has a number on it.  You are allowed 10 bits for the number on each box.

With that numbering scheme, you can number 1024 boxes (0-1023.)

1. Each box holds 8 bits.
2. Each box has a 10 bit number to identify it.
3. You can have 1024 bytes with 8 bits each, addressed by a 10 bit number.

Comment: So no matter how many boxes we have, each box always contains 8 bits?

Comment: Right.   Think of the adresses like the numbers on houses on a street.

Comment: But what if we want to store bigger values inside our boxes? Do we have to store that value in multiple boxes?

Comment: Then you need bigger boxes.  Instead of a byte, you could use 16 bit values.

Comment: [Have a look at the Wikipedia page on "Word" sizes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture))

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

With 10 bits, you can address 1024 locations.

It appears somebody has made the assumption, and left it unstated, that a location stores 8 bits. A location can store any size word you like, from 1 bit, though 8 bits, to a very large number of bits indeed (often called a VLIW, or very long instruction word, 256 or more).

Because of the history of its development, PC memory stores 8 bits in each addressable location, which is why the assumption above is often made, and is usually right. Other architectures may address memory of different word widths.

As a matter of practicality and speed, PC memory is often organised into wider words, 64 bit is not uncommon. When addressing a wider memory a word at a time, the lowest few address bits will always be set to zero, the 3 lowest in the case of 64 bit memory. This is called a 'word aligned' access. It's often still possible to address individual bytes in such a memory, though this is rarely done as it's horribly inefficient.

The width of the memory does not directly affect the sizes of variables we can store. If we want to store a 64 bit variable, then we just use 8 sequential bytes to hold it. If we have two of those next to each other in memory, then the address of the second will be 8 bytes further on. It's only a matter of efficiency and machine architecture whether the memory that holds these values is 8 bits wide, perhaps for an MCU, or 32 or 64 bits wide, for an older or newer PC respectively.

Answer (score 2):

For reference: 1 byte = 8 bits

You're confusing **addresses** and their size with **data** and their size.
You can have any size address and any size data. They don't have to be 1:1 or any specific ratio.
In your example, it sounds like you've got a **data size** of 8 bits (one byte) and an **address size** of 10 bits. Therefore you have 2^10 locations as you said with each location being one byte which gives you 1024 bytes (1kB).

But there's many different architectures. If you're designing your own, you could make up your own data size and address size to be whatever you want to be. You follow the same process to find out how many total bits or bytes you have. For example, you could have 7 bit addressing and 11 bits of data *per* address. This would result in 2**7=128 locations with each location having 11 bits. Which would equal 1408 total bits of data. Divide that by 8 and you have 176 bytes of data you can access.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused with bytes and adress of bytes. with 10 bits you can write 1024 different adresses which can be used to access 1024 differents bytes. But with 10 bits you obsviously cannot store all of these values.